# SQL Server : use another table on another Database in my database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database named `Db1`, and I have a table named `table1` inside it.

I want to get join between this table and another table in `DB2` named `Table2`

Please help me

Comment: link server is for another server, I think this problem was in same server

Comment: That title doesn't seem to match the question at all.

Comment: May we now why do you want to do it? It doesn't seems good way of handling things until you really need it. If you are doing this in web app, I must say there are other ways you can deal with this situation.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg I change title

Comment: Title is saying Another Database. But in description both the tables were present in same database `DB1`

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Correct cross-database join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query:

```
Select * from Table2 inner Join DB1.dbo.Table1 on table2.fkey=DB1.dbo.Table1.key
```

If you want use this a lot of times,
You can Use Create View in DB2

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vDB1_Table1]
AS
SELECT     *    FROM         DB1.dbo.Table1

GO
```

then use `vDB1_Table1` for access table1.

another way is to use SYNONYM

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[syn_db1_table1] FOR [DB1].[dbo].[Table1]
GO
```

also, you can create synonyms in `management studio` with right click in `synonyms` section of table in object explorer and then click `new synonym...`
[image: Create Synonym]

now in DB2 use this query

```
Select * from Table2 inner Join vDB1_Table1 on table2.fkey=vDB1_Table1.key
```

or

```
 Select * from Table2 inner Join [syn_db1_table1] on table2.fkey=[syn_db1_table1].key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from 
db1.dbo.table1 t1 
    inner join 
db2.dbo.table2 t2
    on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```